# Is it possible to run Spark jobs (like the WordCount sample) in the local mode on Cygwin?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cygwin, rdd

I am executing a simple Spark code for reading a file from local system but getting error below is the code on Cygwin console :

```
val orders = sc.textFile("C:///DataResearch/retail_db/orders")

orders.first()
```

after executing `orders.first()` I am getting below error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:661)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:567)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$RawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:542)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:42)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1797)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1307)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1302)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1342)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1341)
        at .<init>(<console>:18)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:734)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:983)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.loadAndRunReq$1(IMain.scala:573)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:604)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:568)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.reallyInterpret$1(ILoop.scala:760)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:805)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:717)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine$1(ILoop.scala:581)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.innerLoop$1(ILoop.scala:588)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:591)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:882)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:837)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:136)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:837)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.main(ILoop.scala:904)
        at xsbt.ConsoleInterface.run(ConsoleInterface.scala:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:107)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.console(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
        at sbt.Console.sbt$Console$$console0$1(Console.scala:22)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Console$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Console.scala:23)
        at sbt.Logger$$anon$4.apply(Logger.scala:84)
        at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:248)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have referred to below, but not sure how it works :

[Is it possible to run Hadoop jobs (like the WordCount sample) in the local mode on Windows without Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516865/is-it-possible-to-run-hadoop-jobs-like-the-wordcount-sample-in-the-local-mode)

Comment: does it works from windows CMD ?

Comment: Did anyone looked at this issue , it will be really helpful for me

Comment: I have not tried with CMD

Comment: Hadop is a Java program and cyywin has no Java, so first you make it run under windows and after you can try to make it works also under cygwin. If you are not sure of first step make no sense to try two steps at once.

Comment: Just now executed on CMD got error :
Failed to locate winutils binary in the hadoop binary path ?

could you please help me to setup winutils  path ?

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [doc](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html), it explains how to run Spark under Windows

Comment: Issue is resolved followed below link :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38077006/error-while-installing-hadoop-2-7-2-on-windows-10/38090348